# Extract specific symbols from pandas cells, then replace them with values from a dict where they are keys

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this, well these are two of the columns:

```
Index  MSC Primary   MSC Secondary
0       05C25      (05C20 20F05)
1       20-04      (20F55 62Qxx)
2       13F20      (17B20 22E40 22F30 65Fxx)
3       05Exx      (20-04 20H20)
4       20G40      (05C25)
```

These are MSC codes, corresponding to different areas of science. I need to replace each code with the corresponding subject from this dict here: https://mathscinet.ams.org/msnhtml/msc2020.pdf , some of them are:
"""
00 General and overarching topics; collections
01 History and biography
03 Mathematical logic and foundations
05 Combinatorics
"""

First I need to isolate the first two digits from each code, for instance `05C25` to transform to `05` or from the second column `(05E15 14H50)` to transform to `05, 14`.

Then I need each number replaced by the corresponding science for example `05, 14` to become `Combinatorics, Algebraic geometry`.
This is all tricky form be because I am new to Python and the second column has different number of MSC codes in each cell so I cannot use indexing there.

I know for the first column I can use indexing:

```
df['MSC Primary'] = [x[:2] for x in df['MSC Primary']]
```

But this is not working for the other column, because there are several secondary MSC codes, different for each cell.

Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

Using a regex to get the first two chars of each "word":

```py
df["MSC Secondary"] = (
    df["MSC Secondary"]
    .str.extractall(r"[ \(](\w{2})")[0]
    .map(d)
    .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
)
```

Using:

- [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) apply the regex [`[ \(](\w{2})`](https://regex101.com/r/WDqTbw/2/) to get the first two characters from all words in each row
- [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) map the dict, `d` over the `[0]` (zero-eth) match group
- [`groupby(level=0).agg(list)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) to group the Series by index (`level=0`) and put them back into lists (`.agg(list)`)

---

Through a few chained pandas str methods:

```py
d = dict(...)
df["MSC Secondary"] = (
    df["MSC Secondary"]
    .str.strip("()")
    .str.split()
    .explode()
    .str[:2]
    .map(d)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(list)
)

#   MSC Primary                                      MSC Secondary
# 0       05C25  [Combinatorics, Group theory and generalizations]
# 1       20-04     [Group theory and generalizations, Statistics]
# 2       13F20  [Nonassociative rings and algebras, Topologica...
# 3       05Exx  [Group theory and generalizations, Group theor...
# 4       20G40                                    [Combinatorics]
```

Here we use:

- [`pandas.Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) to remove the parentheses
- [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the substrings into lists
- [`pandas.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to turn every element in each list into it's own row
- [`str[:2]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) to slice of the first two characters
- [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map your linked dict
- [`grouby(level=0).agg(list)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) to group the Series by index (`level=0`) and put them back into lists (`.agg(list)`)

Comment: Hi @Alex and thank you for your answer, I am trying to test it but I am failing to put this PDF https://mathscinet.ams.org/msnhtml/msc2020.pdf into a dictionary `d`

Comment: You can copy the text from the first page into a python script as a variable, `x="""00 ..."""` then create the dict like so: `d = {l[:2]: l[2:] for l in x.splitlines()}`

Comment: Thank you so much Alex, the dictionary worked and the first option with the Regex worked fine, absolute magic, bless you !!!

Comment: I've just updated the regex one because `\b` also includes hyphens (`-`) so it wasn't 100% right!

Comment: I updated it, thank you again. I need to create some visualisations with these columns but from the Secondary the cells data type is `list` and it does not work for getting `unique()` values. Now I am trying to change this somehow to string.

Comment: You can replace the `list` in `.agg(list)` with `", ".join` (or `lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, x)` if there will be unmatched codes) which will make them strings separated by commas. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dictionary of MSC codes is `d`, this works:

```
>>> df["MSC Secondary"].apply(lambda x: [d.get(s[:2]) for s in x.replace("(","").replace(")","").split(" ")])

0    [Combinatorics, Group theory and generalizations]
1       [Group theory and generalizations, Statistics]
2    [Nonassociative rings and algebras, Topologica...
3    [Group theory and generalizations, Group theor...
4                                      [Combinatorics]
```

Comment: Hi @not_speshal and thank you for your answer, I am trying to test it but I am failing to put this PDF mathscinet.ams.org/msnhtml/msc2020.pdf into a dictionary d